# Background positions

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-position

This Image I'm using  for making 3 direction animation.
I need to show only first character of this image. Well i am using background position-

```
background-position:0px 200px;
```

But it is showing full image here.

**Styles**

```
position:absolute;
    top: 40px;left: 40px;
background-position: 0px 200px;
```

Image-
[image: Image i want to use for first character]

Please guide me through Js fiddle.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/9RYph/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link i hope this will help for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9RYph/7/

```
div {

    top: 40px;left: 40px;
    background-size:100%;
    background:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuAjg.jpg');
    width: 50%;
    height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
img{
clip:rect(0px,300px,auto,0px);
position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `img` but `background-position` property wont apply on `img` element, you need to use `background-image` property in your CSS and need to set the width of the element here, so if the character width is say around `100px` and height of `200px`, than set `height` and `width` as `200px` and `100px` respectively

```
<div></div>

div {
   height: 200px;
   width: 100px;
   background-image: url();
   background-position: ;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   /* Other styles goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put this image in a div as background and then use `background-position` property.

`background-position` only works if you use background image.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ranasaani/9RYph/5/)**

Comment: Thanks, i get what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the background image in the `#character` id:

```
background: url(http://img391.imageshack.us/img391/432/scorpionortholp0.jpg)
```

Then add the `width` and `height` properties to suit your needs.